# Google Sheets save data range to PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to save a sheet as a PDF in my drive - and I've been successful with this code:

```
function createPDF() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
    
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('my folder ID')
    
    
    var tempFile = SpreadsheetApp.create("TempSheetv2")
    
    sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile.getId()))
    
    var tempSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile.getId())
    var tempSheet = tempSS.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
    tempSS.deleteSheet(tempSheet)
    
    var blob = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile.getId()).getAs('application/pdf')
    
    var pdf = folder.createFile(blob).setName("Test PDF for 8th Grade")
    
    DriveApp.getFileById(tempFile.getId()).setTrashed(true)
    
    console.log(data)
    }
```

The only problem is - the PDF has 27 pages (26 of which are blank). Is there a way to limit the PDF to only the data range?

Comment: It would be easier if you share example of your spreadsheet. Since it's likely it has something wrong inside. Something like a couple letters or numbers in the cell AA1000. The obvious solution would be to check and to clear all redundant rows beforehand.

Comment: I was able to figure it out - it wasn't "values" per se - but I did have cell borders that were causing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function createPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const name = sheet.getName();//change
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getName() != name).forEach(s => s.hideSheet());//change
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid')
  var tempFile = SpreadsheetApp.create("TempSheetv2")
  sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile.getId()))
  var tempSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile.getId())
  var tempSheet = tempSS.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  tempSS.deleteSheet(tempSheet)
  var blob = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile.getId()).getAs('application/pdf')
  folder.createFile(blob).setName("Test PDF for 8th Grade")
  DriveApp.getFileById(tempFile.getId()).setTrashed(true)
  console.log(data)
}
```